# How to create a dynamic angular form using reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I need to create a dynamic form using angular react. But this for has many sub form groups and these groups may change by form select box values.

```
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    department: new FormControl('')
  });
```

Department types are `'a', 'b', 'c'`.

if user select `'a'`, I will add a new FormGroup named `"departmentSettings"` in profileForm

```
aFormGroup =  new FormGroup({
    xWorkTime: new FormControl(''),
    yWorkTime: new FormControl('')
})

profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    department: new FormControl(''),
    departmentSettings: new FormGroup({
        xWorkTime: new FormControl(''),
        yWorkTime: new FormControl('')
    })
});
```

if user select `'b'`, I will add a new `FormGroup` in profileForm

```
bFormGroup =  new FormGroup({
    someProperty: new FormControl(''),
    otherProperty: new FormControl('')
})

profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    department: new FormControl(''),
    departmentSettings:  new FormGroup({
        someProperty: new FormControl(''),
        otherProperty: new FormControl('')
    })
});
```

The other cases are like this. So how can I do this using simple way in angular?

Comment: This is a polymorphic form and https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form is perfect for that. Ex in the readme + demo source code :)

Comment: Just a suggestion: you can simplify your form generation greatly if you use the [Form Builder API](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder). Can simplify to `aFormGroup = this.fb.group({xWorkTime : '', yWorkTime:''});`

Answer (score 0):

In your html, add a (change)='someFunction()' attribute to the department input.

```
<input matInput type="select" #departmentInput formControlName="department"
                 (change)="doChange($event)">
```

This will trigger that function when the value of the input has changed, then you can add a new form control to your reactive form.

Reactive forms has an FormGroup.addControl() method to do this.
https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup